# Multiple upload buttons on one page

Tags: php, uploader

I wanted to have multiple upload buttons on one page but it keeps giving me error on the first upload "query was empty". The second uploader works perfectly (s2). Here is my code:

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['s1']))
{

$qset = "select frontimg1 from cat";
$rset = mysql_query($qset) or die(mysql_error());
$aset = mysql_fetch_array($rset);
unset($aset);


    $ImageName = $_FILES['images']['name'];
    if(!empty($ImageName))
        {
    $t = time();
    $NewImageName = "$t$ImageName";
    copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "../img/header_images/$NewImageName");
    $q1 = "update cat set 
                    frontimg1='$NewImageName'";             
        }
    mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div class=alert fade in><b>Website settings was updated successfully!</b>    </div>";
}

elseif(isset($_POST['s2']))
{

$qset = "select frontimg2 from cat";
$rset = mysql_query($qset) or die(mysql_error());
$aset = mysql_fetch_array($rset);
unset($aset);


    $ImageName = $_FILES['images']['name'];
    if(!empty($ImageName))
        {
    $t = time();
    $NewImageName = "$t$ImageName";
    copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "../img/header_images/$NewImageName");
    $q1 = "update cat set 
                    frontimg2='$NewImageName'";             
        }
    mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div class=alert fade in><b>Website settings was updated successfully!</b>        </div>";
}

//get the main site settings
$qset = "select * from cat";
$rset = mysql_query($qset) or die(mysql_error());
$aset = mysql_fetch_array($rset);


?>

<form method=post name=f1 onsubmit="return CheckSettings();" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <table align=center width="90%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=2 class=header><font size="2"> 
        <b>WEBSITE SETTINGS</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="form_request">Current Header Image:</td>
      <td class="form_answer">
        <p><label> 
          <? if($aset['frontimg1']==""){?>
          NA 
          <?}else{?>
          <img src="../img/header_images/<?=$aset['frontimg1']?>"> </label></p>
        <p><label> 
          <?}?>
          </label></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="form_request">Upload New Header Image:</td>
      <td class="form_answer"><label> 
        <input type="file" name="images">
        <br />
        (Leave it blank to keep the same image)</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td> 
        <input type=submit name=s1 value=Save class="btn btn-primary">
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td class="form_request">Second Header Image:</td>
      <td class="form_answer">
        <p><label> 
          <? if($aset['frontimg2']==""){?>
          NA 
          <?}else{?>
          <img src="../img/header_images/<?=$aset['frontimg2']?>"> </label></p>
        <p><label> 
          <?}?>
          </label></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td class="form_request">Upload New Header Image:</td>
      <td class="form_answer"><label> 
        <input type="file" name="images">
        <br />
        (Leave it blank to keep the same image)</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td> 
        <input type=submit name=s2 value=Save class="btn btn-primary">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Any help would be great

Comment: are you uploading any image?

Comment: Start by spacing these out `<?}?>` to `<? }?>` - `<?}else{?>` to `<? }else{?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file input fields both have the same name (`images`) so s2 will always override s1. Try changing them to be unique ie `imagess1` and `imagess2`.

Answer (score 0):

your `$ImageName` is getting empty value because you have two  `<input type="file" name="images">` elements.So while submitting the form the first `images` overwriting with the second `images` which is not having any value in it, So change the name of second input file name tag.

```
if(!empty($ImageName))--> this is empty and if block will not be executed
    {
$t = time();
$NewImageName = "$t$ImageName";
copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "../img/header_images/$NewImageName");
$q1 = "update cat set 
                frontimg2='$NewImageName'";             
    }
mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());--->so here `$q1` is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I noticed some syntax errors that you may want to address:
in this line:

    <input type=submit name=s1 value=Save class="btn btn-primary"> 

the *value* attribute needs the following text string surrounded by quote marks
the *type* attribute needs the following text string surrounded by quotes
the *name* attribute needs the following text string surrounded by quotes
the corrections of the syntax results in:

    <input type="submit" name="s1" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"> 

similarly, this line:

    <input type=submit name=s2 value=Save class="btn btn-primary">

should be:

    <input type="submit" name="s2" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">

The HTML language requires quotes, which kind of quotes (single or double) 
is arbitrary,  so long as they match,
If the lack of quotes works, it is simply a idiosyncrasy of the browser being used.

Regarding the sequence:

       <p><label> 
      <?}?>
      </label></p>

The PHP items are handled in the server, 
before the html is passed to the client (your web browser)
Therefore, the above sequence becomes:

    <p><label>
    <label></p>

which does absolutely nothing useful.
So the sequence should be:

    <?}?>

BTW:
1) The *label* tag is to assist mouse users to click an input by 'expanding' 
the clickable area into the *label* text.
I.E.  wrapping the input area with the *label* tag does work, it accomplishes nothing
Better to write the *label* tag on the text before the input area, 
and link the two via the *for=* and *id=* attributes, like so:

    <td class="form_request" >
        <label for="image2">Second Header Image:</label></td>
    <td class="form_answer">
        <p> 
            <? if($aset['frontimg2']==""){?>
            NA 
            <?}else{?>
           <img id="image2" src="../img/header_images/<?=$aset['frontimg2']?>">
        </p>

As a final note regarding the use of the '<?' shortcut for the '<?php' tag, 
taken from the php manual:

    PHP also allows for short open tags <? and ?> 
    (which are discouraged because they are only available 
    if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, 
    or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option. 

Also, IMO: they make the code much harder to read.
```